# How to insert a paragraph based on a drop-down list on Word for MacOS?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, office365

I have a Word document for reporting on performed data analysis that serves as a template. Inside it there is a section when one can list which data sources were used. These sources are always from one finite list of sources. What I have now is all of these sources and their descriptions listed as paragraphs that are removed when some source is not being used. What I'd like to do is to have a drop-down list from which I can select sources I need that will be inserted as separate paragraphs.

I have tried Combo Box but it gives me a possibility to insert a single line and what I need is a full paragraph with bullet points. I tried to do it using AutoText and AutoTextList but it is depended on a style and style removes bullet point list from there.

Maybe there is some good solution for that? I also tried to do it using VBA but some of the features seem to not be available on MacOS.

Comment: Would the AutoTextList field help? https://support.microsoft.com/office/591cd0be-589b-4aae-9624-db427a19a1c8

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to set this up is to include all the text in the document, but have it formatted as hidden text. The part is easy, because your document is already set up that way, you just have to use **Home>Font** and check the **Hidden** attribute to make it invisible. In Word for Mac, use **Word>Preferences>View** and check the **Hidden text** option to make hidden text visible on-screen while you're setting this up.

Then each paragraph is wrapped in a bookmark. The dropdown would then run a macro that that reads the index of the selected dropdown choice, then formats the bookmarked text as visible.

The exact VBA code to get the dropdown selection depends on what type of dropdown control, you use. Legacy Formfields are included in the Word for Mac program interface, but with VBA, you can also add Content Control dropdowns. Here is my article about [using VBA to create Content Controls in Word for Mac](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/). I also have a free add-in to make content controls in Word for Mac that I send to people who subscribe to my blog.

Once you figure out what control type you want to use, the VBA to show text looks something like this:

```
With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("Paragraph1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    .Bookmarks("Paragraph2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    .Bookmarks("Paragraph3").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    .Bookmarks("Paragraph4").Range.Font.Hidden = True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Doesn't it mean it would still be inside the document but just hidden? I wouldn't like for someone to accidentally make it visible again since it would make the report incorrect.

Comment: You can include an AutoOpen macro that checks if hidden text is visible in the Word installation, and then set it to be invisible. If it doesn't display on-screen, it can't be selected or accidentally made visible.